# Apex input field of Type lookup is taking "Name" instead of "ID"

Tags: apex, visualforce, lookup, inputfield

I have a inputfield of type lookup. It should contain Id of the reference Account but it takes the Name. Alert is showing name of the Account, where it should return Id. Please Advise.

```
<apex:inputField id="ShareInputField" value="{!Form_Requests_abv__c.Account_abv__c}">
```

[image]

[image: Alert Showing null Account Id]

Comment: try alerting {!Form_Requests_abv__c.Account_abv__c} it should show an Id

Comment: I tried this, But it is returning Null

Comment: This is because you probably have not submitted the form yet. Why do you need to pass value to a controller with Javascript? Once you set the lookup and press some button or link on your form Id that you are looking for should be available in controller as Form_Requests_abv__c.Account_abv__c.

Comment: I have a Dependent Address SelectList, that will contain Address of the Account selected from the LookUp dialogue. So i need here the ActionSupport to pass the Account Id in controller and retrieve the corresponding Address IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your visualforce page, can you try

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!accountSelected}"/>
```

And then once you select an account it will be available in your controller

```
public void accountChanged(){
    System.debug('----->' + Form_Requests_abv__c.Account_abv__c);
    // Your other logic here to retrieve address Ids
}
```

Comment: ya thats i'm doing...but i also need to select the Address of that account from the UI itself for that i need to pass account Id in such way inorder to fetch associated address ids

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you want with that Id. Why can't you fetch associated address ids in your controller once Account was chosen? If you don`t want the whole page to be refreshed on account change you might want to use ActionRegion for Account and Address.

Comment: I've used ActionRegion...but thats not my question...i'm unable to understand how a lookup type Inputfield is returning Account Name i. e string type here.

Comment: It is returning ID. But this id is stored in a hidden field on your form. For example go to detail page of some account and copy its ID, then go back to your page and select that account with a lookup. Right click and press inspect in your browser to open page code and press Ctrl+F(search on a page) and paste there Id of selected Account. It will show you where the Id is stored. So string is stored only in UI for user convenience.

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behaviour for apex:inputField try to use apex:inputText

Comment: This one is a Lookup field and I want that Lookup icon to appear, so that onclicking a lookup dialogue box will open and allow the user to choose from a list of Accounts. Using InputText will not serve this purpose

Comment: Ok, I didnt mentioned that Id will contain in your field Form_Requests_abv__c.Account_abv__c and on UI you will see a Name of the record. So in APEX in field Form_Requests_abv__c.Account_abv__c you will see  Id of the record

Comment: In the Alert when I print This.value it is showing the Account Name not the Account Id. But ideally it should print AccountId

Comment: To get id just place '{! Form_Requests_abv__c.Account_abv__c}' into JS with quotes. It will work if it is a lookup. Lookup fields are storing Id value in SF database

Comment: yes i've tried this ..it is returning Null

Comment: It should be filled in for current object on the moment of the rendering VF page.
If it is not filled for current object it will return null. 
You can add remote action that will do the work by name of the related object.  apex:inputField is rendered to html and it depends on type of the field.